# SAS Grid Enabling

Tags: sas

I have to pull a lot of data and I am trying to grid enable it to run faster.  Unfortunately, I am not a SAS coder so I am trying to modify existing code.  I keep getting a 'no matching %DO statement for the %END' error in the waitfor *all* section of the log.  I am not even sure this would work otherwise.

Does someone have grid experience to help me out?

```
%let _sdtm=%sysfunc(datetime());
%macro splitmonths(begmonth=,endmonth=);
%let rc=%sysfunc(grdsvc_enable(_all_,server=SASApp));
options autosignon;

%do imth=&begmonth %to &endmonth;
    signon t&imth;
    %syslput imth=&imth/remote=t&imth;
    rsubmit t&imth wait=no;
        PROC SQL;
        CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_VW_HOUPOSSW_FACT_&imth AS 
            SELECT t1.outletfamily, 
                t1.ppmonth, 
                t1.itemnumber, 
                /* Dollars */
                (SUM(t1.totalvalue)) FORMAT=DOLLAR20. AS Dollars
            FROM HOUPWP7.vw_houpossw_fact t1
            WHERE t1.ppmonth = &imth;
            GROUP BY t1.outletfamily,
                   t1.ppmonth,
                   t1.itemnumber;
        QUIT;
    endrsubmit;
%end

waitfor _all_
    %do imth=&begmonth %to &endmonth;
        t&imth
    %end;
    ;
signoff _all_;


data newdata;
    set
    %do imth=&begmonth %to &endmonth;
        newdata&imth
    %end;
    ;
run;

proc datasets lib=work;
    %do imth=&begmonth %to &endmonth;
        delete newdata&imth;
    %end
quit;
%mend splitmonths
%splitmonths (begmonth=541, endmonth=588)


%let _edtm=%sysfunc(datetime());
%let _runtm=%sysfunc(putn(&_edtm - &_sdtm, 12.4));
%put It took &_runtm second to run the program;enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding semi-colon to end the `%end` macro statement just before the start of the `waitfor` statement.

```
%end;

waitfor _all_
```